# table won't refresh after deleting a row although database is successfully updated

Tags: angular

I am newbie in programming. I tried this code it successfully deletes the data in database but it won't refresh the list. Please help me

this is the code i used in **/instrument-list.component.ts**

```
 delete(instrument: Instrument_Model): void {  
    this.instrumenrService.deleteInstruments(instrument.traceNO)  
     .subscribe(data => {  
    this.instruments = this.instruments.filter(u => u!== instrument);  
    })  
  }
```

this is the code i used in **/instrument-list-data.service.ts**

```
deleteInstruments(id: number):Observable<Instrument_Model> {  
  return this.http.delete<Instrument_Model>(this.baseUrl +"delete/"+id);  
}
```

**when i added cosole.log() it generates this error**

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: 
"http://localhost:8080/instrument/delete/13", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at         
JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "succesfully deleted"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit:ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for                     
http://localhost:8080/instrument/delete/13"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/instrument/delete/13"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

**here is the html template**

```html
  <table style="border: 5rem;border-color: black ">
      <tr >
      <th>traceNO</th>
    <th>instrumentID</th>
    <th>operatorName</th>
    <th>operatorEmail</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>instrumentName</th>
    <th>Control</th>
          </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let instrument of instruments">
  <td>{{instrument.traceNO}}</td>
<td>{{instrument.instrumentID}}</td>
<td>{{instrument.operatorName}}</td>
<td>{{instrument.operatorEmail}}</td>
<td>{{instrument.price}}</td>
<td>{{instrument.instrumentName}}</td>
<td><button id  (click)="delete(instrument)"> Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

here is the **Instrument_Model** template

```
export interface Instrument_Model{
traceNO: number,
instrumentID:string,
operatorName:string,
operatorEmail:string,
price:number,
instrumentName:string
}
```

please help me to find out where everything went wrong.Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you put console.log in the subscribe block, what do you get? does the code flow get to that?

Comment: are you using a library to display "the list"/table? If so, which library is it? Some libraries require you to run a .update() / .refresh() function, you might want to check the docs. You may also want to include your template (html) along in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in the back end. The error happened because i didn't pass a json object from my back end.Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `delete()` method with below code

```
delete(instrument: Instrument_Model): void {  
    this.instrumenrService.deleteInstruments(instrument.traceNO)  
     .subscribe(data => {  
    this.instruments = this.instruments.filter(u => u.traceNO !== instrument.traceNO);  
    })  
  }
```

Comment: can you please share the `Instrument_Model` property structure